# Python to Remove Column in CSV and Write new CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

The input CSV file is below.

```
Elements,FileID,Loadcase,Step,Layer,CornerID,E-Strain components IP:E11
41,2,1,0,SectionPoint 1,0,0
41,2,1,0,SectionPoint 1,5,0
41,2,1,0,SectionPoint 1,35,0
```

In this file, I want to remove the entire `CornerID` column and write a new CSV file.
Note: the script should work with header name and remove that column . Not like in the way of Column indices level deleting. because like this I have multiple files, in some files the column number will not be the same.

can anyone help me to get python code for this?

import csv

inputf = "D:\PyLe\csvinput\Report_E-Strain components IP_E11_2_1.csv"
outfile = "D:\PyLe\csvinput\Report_E-Strain components IP_E11_2_1_new.csv"

```
import csv

    with open(inputf, newline='') as csvfile:
        outfile1 = open (outfile , 'w')
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

for row in reader:
      del (row['CornerID'])
      spamwriter = csv.writer(outfile1, delimiter=' ',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
      spamwriter.writerow(row)
      print (type(row))
```

this code is reading the csv file and deleting that columnl. but its not writing out the new file with csv format.

Comment: How about `df.drop(['CornerID'], axis=1, inplace=True)` and then save it as a csv?

Comment: please send me the full code..:)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go is to use `pandas`. It is a common python module to handle tabular data.

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv("pathtoyourcsvfile.csv")
csv = csv.drop("CornerID", axis=1)
csv.to_csv("pathtoyournewcsvfile.csv")
```

Comment: Please send the link where i can download pandas

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-from-pypi

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas installation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html)

You can first [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), then [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the column and then save it as a csv using  [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_CSV_file_name')
df.drop(['CornerID'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('path_or_buf_to_save_new_csv')
```

Comment: Could be. I am not aware of that. You should also remember that this is not a code writing platform. If you want a code that doesn't use Pandas, then I suggest you write your code and if any problem arises, you can post the problem here

Comment: import csv

inputf = "D:\\PyLe\\csvinput\\Report_E-Strain components IP_E11_2_1.csv"
outfile = "D:\\PyLe\\csvinput\\Report_E-Strain components IP_E11_2_1_new.csv"


import csv
with open(inputf, newline='') as csvfile:
    outfile1 = open (outfile , 'w')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
          del (row['CornerID'])
          spamwriter = csv.writer(outfile1, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
          spamwriter.writerow(row)
          print (type(row))

inputf.close()
outfile.close()

Comment: Through all of the blog posts on using this library for this purposes, none of them have the key last method call "df.to_csv('path')"